# SSH - what is the meaning of permission denied(publickey, password)?

Tags: ssh

sorry if the question may be vague or not but I noticed that whenever I have tried to login to a ssh server it usually says "permission denied(publickey, password" or "permission denied(publickey, password,x, y)" where x and y are other strings but do these indicate what I could use to login to the server or are these the requirements needed to login to the server?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is typically displayed by the SSH client when you do not provide valid login credentials and the server refuses to grant you access.

After failing to authenticate successfully the ssh server responds with an error message that indicates what authentication methods it supports and is willing to accept (in order of preference). See: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252#section-5.1

Those supported methods are the ones between the <kbd>(</kbd> <kbd>)</kbd> braces in the `Permission denied (...)` error.

Supported authentication methods are usually one or more of: GSSAPI-based authentication, host-based authentication, public key authentication, challenge-response authentication, and password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the SSH in very very verbose mode:

## ssh -vvv user@ipAddress

and read through the messages. I had issues on RHEL 8.3 after an update b/c it changed all the cipers and macs in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. I finally moved the correct settings to the '.d' folder under there in the redhat_05.conf file so it wouldn't be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies